# Cannot Convert Const Char[21] to Char?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, default-value

I'm having trouble with conversion. I cannot use strings in this program so I have to use `char`'s - I get the error:

```
error C2664: 'printText' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [21]' to 'char'
1>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
```

I've tried converting it to a const pointer:

```
void printText(const char* text[100] = "notextgiven"...
```

but it doesn't seem to help, gives me more errors than anything.

My Program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printText(char, char, int);

int main(){
    printText("I hear and I forget.", "*", 15);
}

void printText(char text[100] = "notextgiven", char symbol = ' ', int repeat = 10){
    int temp = 0;
    while(temp < repeat){
        cout << symbol;
            temp++;
    }

    cout << text;

    temp = 0;
    while(temp < repeat){
        cout << symbol << endl;
            temp++
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, `"*"` shoud be `'*'` instead...

Comment: Do you know what the difference is between a char (character) and a string?

Comment: @Derp Don't update the code to your question in response to the answers. Keep it as it is. What if other people come on this question and find no errors in your code, but see that you are asking for help for some non-existent problem? They will be confused. Next time, please make no changes to your question or your code. The only reason you should do so it is for clarity.

Comment: @jalf, I believe a string is a bunch of chars, where as chars is a single character or a char array is an array of characters.

Comment: @David :S   should I undo the changes?

Comment: @Derp Yup. It would be better if you did.

Comment: Ok I reverted it back to the original

Comment: @Derp Thanks for reverting. By the way, in addition to @mathematician1975 's answer, you're also missing a semi-colon where it says `temp++` at the bottom. (Don't change it in the question of course)! :]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not the right way to define your function for what you are  trying to do

```
void printText(char text[100] = "notextgiven", char symbol = ' ', int repeat = 10)
```

try this instead

```
void printText(const char* text, char symbol, int repeat)
```

this should allow your program to compile. Also change this line

```
 printText("I hear and I forget.", "*", 15);
```

to

```
printText("I hear and I forget.", '*', 15);
                                  ^ ^
```

single quotes are used for a single char variable, double quotes treat it as a string literal. As this is homework, you may have been asked to specifically use `char*` but since you are using C++ in general you would be much better off using `std::string`

Comment: I'm giving default values to the function. Also, as homework I cannot use strings.

Comment: In that case you usually specify them at function declaration rather than implementation.

Comment: @Derp if you want to give default values to function then give them in declaration of function, not in definition of function.

Comment: @Derp Really use std::string unless you have to use char*

Comment: @mathematician1975 I've updated my question using your current advice and getting `Too many characters in character constant` on my default characters and passing character arrays.

Comment: @Derp You really shouldnt change any code in your question as this leads to a lot of confusion and can make current answers meaningless.

Comment: @mathematician1975 I reverted it back to the original but using your answers I get limits to how many characters I can have in my character array, even if I make the array hold [1000] and only have 1 default character? Why is this?

Comment: @Derp lose the array completely. Change your declaration to `void printText(const char* text = "notextgiven", char symbol = ' ', int repeat = 10);` and your definition to what it is above in my answer. I have just checked this compiles

Comment: Really really look into the documentation of std::string - it will make future coding so much easier

Comment: @mathematician1975 Thank you for your help, it compiles and works! Not to drag this on but do you know why it won't compile if I'm using a character array? I mean if I'm setting aside 100 characters and don't go over the limit, why can't it just fill that space with the characters?

Comment: I am a bit confused now as the question changed. But what you have above in the question `const char* text[100]` is actually an array of 100 char* not char. You need to read about string literals and how they are treated in C++, also read about how arrays decay to a pointer to their first element when passed into a function. But really look into `std::string` it is very very useful

Answer (score 2):

In your original function you first tried to put an entire string inside a single character - which is obviously not possible. Then, you tried a reasonable solution, which isn't allowed by C++ mainly for historical reasons.

Change your `printText` to

```
void printText(const char *, char, int);
```

Why is this needed?

- a C string is an array of `char`s;
- arrays cannot be passed by value in C/C++ (for no particular reason<sup>1</sup>);
- the name of an array decays to the pointer to its first element, and if you have a pointer to the first element you can index the whole array;

For this reason, when you pass arrays to C/C++ functions you actually pass a pointer to their first element; for generic arrays you pass also the size of the array in a separate parameter (otherwise the called function wouldn't know when to stop examining the array), for C strings it's not needed because, by convention, they end at the first '\0' character (the null terminator).

Why the `const`? Because your function do not need to modify the string you are passing to it, so you make clear this fact, and also allow your callers to pass `const` strings without incurring in compile errors (string literals in theory are `const` strings, because they cannot be modified, but they can be converted implicitly to `char *` again for historical reasons).

---

By the way, it's not inherently prohibited to declare a sized array parameter to a function - but, for the aforementioned compatibility problems, it's interpreted as a pointer anyway. You get errors with the default values because you have to specify them in the *declaration* (=prototype) of the function, not in its *definition*.

---

Finally, as other noticed, in your function call

```
printText("I hear and I forget.", "*", 15);
```

the second parameter is a string (because you enclosed it in double quotes), when it should be a simple `char` (enclosed in single quotes).

---

1. IIRC it has something to do with compatibility with B or BCPL or whatever, the point is that there's no intrinsic reason why an array couldn't be passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

You try to pass a string to a function that is, according to how you set it up, only accepting a single character.

`printText` needs to take it's parameters as `char*` instead of `char` (that is: as a sequence of characters instead of a single character).

So instead of `printText(char, char, int);` you need the forward declaration to be `printText(char*, char*, int)`.

Likewise the function signature is supposed to be:

`void printText(char* text = "notextgiven", char* symbol = " ", int repeat = 10)`

Comment: When I add the pointer values, I get errors when I try to add default arguments. Telling me it's incompatible.

Comment: This should work fine, at least it does for me (using VC++). Maybe it's a compiler thing. Make sure you add the default values to the function definition, not to the declaration (so to the one where the function body is).

Answer (score 0):

Note that the error message that you described in your original title isn't exactly the same as your actual error message. (I have taken the liberty to change this.) The "[21]" at the end is **extremely** important. In particular the "[]" symbols represent an array. So the compiler is telling you that you are trying to convert from an **array** of characters to just a single character. Since an array can hold more than one character, it should be obvious why the compiler complains that it cannot do this.

With that explanation out of the way, let's look at how to fix your code. There are three lines that are causing issues in your code:

The function *declaration*:

```
void printText(char, char, int);
```

The function *call*:

```
printText("I hear and I forget.", "*", 15);
```

The function *definition*:

```
void printText(char text[100] = "notextgiven", char symbol = ' ', int repeat = 10){ 
   //...
}
```

These are the three ingredients for creating your own function and they must **all match**! If they don't, the compiler will complain. So let's analyze each of these pieces. First the declaration:

```
void printText(char, char, int);
```

Here you *declare* a function named "printText" which expects three inputs (two characters and one integer) and has not outputs ("void").

Now look at the function definition:

```
void printText(char text[100] = "notextgiven", char symbol = ' ', int repeat = 10){ 
   //...
}
```

This *defines* a function named "printText" with three inputs and no outputs. Take a close look, though. This "printText" function needs a character **array**, a character, and an integer as its inputs. Because this list of inputs differs from those in the declaration, this is actually a **complete different function** than the one declared.

I also want to mention here that a function definition *defines* what the function actually does. This is the code between the "{" and the "}". On the other hand, a function declaration simply states that a function exists *somewhere* but does not state what happens inside the function. In order to satisfy the compiler, we need both. (Technically, the linker is involved, too, but that detail is not important to the current question.)

One more thing: Your function provides default arguments with the "=". I suspect that this is not what you intended. Since you are just starting, I strongly suggest that you remove these as they will just complicate things. When you become more comfortable with functions, then you can learn about default arguments.

Finally, let's look at the function call:

```
printText("I hear and I forget.", "*", 15);
```

Since this line appears in the main() function, it tells the printText() function to do its thing. This line also provides the inputs to the printText() function. Note that the inputs given here are two strings (or character arrays) and an integer. (Anything inside double-quotes -- "" -- is a string, which is also equivalent to a character array.) Now this doesn't match the list of inputs that are described by the function declaration, so the compiler attempts to convert your inputs to the types listed. The compiler complains because it is unable to do so.

I suspect that the you actually want to change the third argument to `'*'`. Note the single-quotes. This is how you indicate a single character in C++ (and most other programming languages).

I hope this explanation helps you understand what is going on with your code. Good luck with learning C++!